# Which was the first sci fi story to feature a character with psychometric powers?

Tags: history-of

According to [Psychometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychometry_(paranormal)),

> Psychometry  also known as token-object reading, or psychoscopy is a
> form of extrasensory perception characterized by the claimed ability
> to make relevant associations from an object of unknown history by
> making physical contact with that object

In Night Head 2041 (2021),

> Naoya Kirihara can see  who was the psychic killing people after
> touching a rock.

In He Is Psychometric (2019) , [He is Psychometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/He_Is_Psychometric)

> After losing his parents in a fire, Lee Ahn (Park Jin-young) acquires
> the power of psychometry, the ability to read a person or an object's
> past through physical contact, and he decides to use it to combat
> criminals.

And in Star Wars (?), [Legends](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Psychometry/Legends)

> Psychometry, also known as postcognition, tai vordrax or telemetry,
> was a Force power that was a mental technique of picking up
> impressions and traces of information about the object touched and the
> events that have surrounded it.

Which was the first sci fi story to feature a character with psychometric powers?

Comment: None of the examples you've given seem to fit the Sci-fi genre - not that this makes the question invalid, just saying.

Comment: Star Wars isn't Sci-Fi?  Seriously?

Comment: I'd say it's fantasy in a Sci-fi setting, but your mileage may vary. @Pete

Comment: I doubt it was the first, but Bob Shaw's The Giaconda Caper (1976) features a "Private Psi"  (psychic detective) with this ability. Any examples earlier than 1976?

Comment: I don't know if it was the first, but psychometry was in Andre Norton's 1973 novel Forerunner Foray

Comment: There's a 1964 Doctor Who story-line that supposedly [references psychometry](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Psychometry), "[The Keys Of Marinius](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/The_Keys_of_Marinus_(TV_story))", but as I can't find the exact specific point in the story-line where it supposedly happens - not an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth, the entry for ESP at sf-encyclopedia.com says: Psychometry, the ability to "read" the history of inanimate objects, is an established part of the repertoire of stage psychics but relatively rare in sf. It features extensively in Colin Wilson's The Philosopher's Stone (1969) and incidentally in Philip E High's Blindfold from the Stars (1979).

Comment: Seems like a gypsy dealing with a werewolf might count.

Comment: The theme index of Everett F. Bleiler's *Science-Fiction: The Early Years* lists 3 novels under the heading of Psychometry: Alfred Denton Cridge, *Utopia, or, The History of an Extinct Planet. Psychometrically Obtained* (1884), Milton W. Ramsey, *Six Thousand Years Hence* (1891), George Du Maurier, *The Martian* (1897). If you're interested you can read Bleiler's detailed reviews at Google Books.

Comment: @lucasbachmann, how does a gypsy dealing with a werewolf match psychometry?

Comment: @Pete just making a joke about gypsy fortune telling where they grab your hand tell you a few things from the past and then see your terrifying future.

Comment: There's something very similar in Randall Garrett's Darcy stories (circa 1963); in the one I remember, magic is used to determine that, yes, the fatal bullet was from this gun.